# Extracting original values from cumulative sum values

Tags: python, beginner, comparative-review

I was writing a function in python to extract original values given a list containing cumulative sum values. For eg -

```
Given : cumulative_sum = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
Output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I came up with two functions A & B and am looking for feedback on them, especially using xrange() vs enumerate().

```
import numpy as np
cumulative = np.cumsum(range(1,10))

def A(cumulative):
    output = [0] * len(cumulative)
    for i in xrange(len(cumulative)-1):
        output[-(i+1)] = cumulative[-(i+1)] - cumulative[-(i+2)]
    output[0] = cumulative[0]
return output

def B(cumulative):
    output = [0] * len(cumulative)
    for i,e in reversed(list(enumerate(cumulative))):
        output[i]=cumulative[i] - cumulative[i-1]
    output[0]=cumulative[0]
return output
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both aren't great. `B` is really complicated, which is unnecessary. `A` has this extra negation:

```
output[-(i+1)] = cumulative[-(i+1)] - cumulative[-(i+2)]
```

You could have just used positive indices (why iterate backwards anyway?):

```
output[i+1] = cumulative[i+1] - cumulative[i]
```

I think sort of thing is best accomplished with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). In particular, there's a `pairwise` recipe:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Which translates directly into what we want to do:

```
def C(cumulative):
    yield cumulative[0]
    for a, b in pairwise(cumulative):
        yield b-a
```

This returns a generator, instead of a list, but generators are typically far more useful anyway. I feel that this approach makes it much more explicit what it is you're actually doing: you're yielding the first element, and then the pairwise difference between the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's element-wise subtraction can be used to leverage the pairwise operation by shifting the cumulative sum.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 10)     # desired output in OP
x_cumsum = np.cumsum(x)  # given in OP

x_cumsum_shifted = np.insert(np.delete(x_cumsum, -1), 0, 0)

_x = x_cumsum - x_cumsum_shifted  # the desired output in OP
```

For instance, if `x_cumsum = [a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d]`,
and `x_cumsum_shifted = [0, a, a+b, a+b+c]`,
therefore `x_cumsum - x_cumsum_shifted = [a, b, c, d]`.